# What is SF Native behavior with trailing whitespace for Text fields?

Tags: order-of-execution

What is Salesforce's native behavior with trailing whitespace for text fields, and when is it removed in the order of operations is it removed? For example suppose a user creates a new opportunity name "AwesomeOpp ", and saves the opp. I am fairly certain the opp will lose the trailing whitespace. When is it removed? Can I see the whitespace  with Before Triggers? workflows?

FWIW the opp was created via the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) documentation, all fields are trimmed at the beginning of step 2, where values are loaded into the record, or sometime earlier than that (this is the earliest point in time I can verify that it happens). This occurs before any other processing, even before checking for required values, maximum field lengths, data types, and so on.

It might even be part of validating that a request is valid (e.g. checking session ID and that the request is well-formed), but it's impossible for an outsider like myself to determine when it happens. All you really need to know is that it happens well before you have any opportunity to detect the situation.

Comment: I read step 2, but I didn't interpret it that way...  however, your conclusion makes sense. Thx again!

Comment: @user11235813 You can verify that the trimming occurs *before* other validations, because you can type in a value like `12345     ` into a number field, and you don't get an error. I don't have a way to determine exactly how early it occurs, but it must be before or during step 2.

Comment: that makes sense! thx